# MOSFET current at very low temperature (4K)

Tags: mosfet, current, semiconductors, conductivity, solid-state-devices

I am trying to model the current at low T. To do so I need to compute the integral between the fermid diract statistic and the conductivity, with respect to energy. My problem is that I cannot understand how can I have something different than 0 for a PMOS as my functions seems totally disconnected in the sens that if one is not zero, the other one is :

[image]

and what I get using python :

[image]

I guess I am missing something but I cannot see it..

Comment: Did you take into account that semiconductors start to behave like an **insulator** at temperatures close to 0 K? This is because the mobility of the charge carriers becomes smaller with lower temperatures.

Comment: At 4K (and even at 100mK) the MOSFET is still working, so I should get some current...